# Django 1.11 - How can I ensure TruncYear to produce Zulu time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, django-1.11

I am using Django 1.11 and Postgres 9.4.

How can I ensure TruncYear to produce Zulu time (2019-10-01T00:00:00Z). I notice it creates datetime with timezone like this (2017-01-01T00:00:00+03:00)

Here is my code for the TruncYear queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth, TruncYear, TruncDay, TruncHour

tracking_in_timeseries_data = Tracking.objects.annotate(
         year=TruncYear('created_at')).values('year', 'venue').annotate(
         count=Count('employee_id', distinct = True)).order_by('year') 

>>> for exp in tracking_in_timeseries_data:
...     print(exp['year'], exp['venue'], exp['count'])

2017-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 4 1
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 2 2
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 3 1
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 4 1
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 5 1
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 6 1


>>> tracking_in_timeseries_data
<QuerySet [{'venue': 4, 'year': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'venue': 2, 'year': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 2}, {'venue': 3, 'year': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'venue': 4, 'year': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'venue': 5, 'year': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'venue': 6, 'year': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}]>
```

And if I serialize it produce this:

serializer.py

```
class TimeseriesYearSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = VenueTSSerializer(read_only=True)
    year = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tracking
        fields = ['venue', 'year', 'count']
```

output:

```
[
    {
      "count": 1,
      "year": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
      "venue_id": 2
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "year": "2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
      "venue_id": 1
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "year": "2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
      "venue_id": 2
    },
    {
      "count": 3,
      "year": "2019-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
      "venue_id": 1
    },
    {
      "count": 3,
      "year": "2019-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
      "venue_id": 2
    }
  ]
```

How can I ensure TruncYear queryset it produce a datetime strings in Zulu time like this 2019-10-01T00:00:00Z rather than with a timezone 2019-01-01T00:00:00+03:00.

UPDATE:
I noticed I temporary fix this by restarting the django service.

```
sudo supervisorctl stop all
sudo supervisorctl start all
```

It was then able to produce Z time like this 2019-10-01T00:00:00Z
But after few hours, it started to produce timezone timeformat like this 2017-01-01T00:00:00+03:00

I also noticed if I rebooted the server, it wont have the Z time. I have to do supervisorctl stop and start then it temporarily seems to fix it.

Here are my code snippet for the supervisor restart

```
/home/user/myapp/gunicorn_start.bash
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myapp.conf
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/01525b78fcdc03071fcd34818820d7f1
```

This is my server version Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

What could be the problem and how to fix it so it consistently produce Zulu time.

Comment: Why do you need a **`DateTimeField`** field for ***year*** instead of **IntegerField**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first thing I noted here is, you are using [**`serializers.DateTimeField`**--DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) field for a ***year*** representation, where the **year** always will be a ***positive integer***.

---

Regarding the timezone issue, Django uses the [**`TIME_ZONE`** settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE) while querying from the database. Here is the minimal SQL query in postgress that happens when you do so,

```
SELECT a,b,c,DATE_TRUNC('year', "tracking_table"."created_at" AT TIME ZONE 'YOUR_TIME_ZONE_VALUE') AS "year" FROM "tracking_table
```

But, fortunately, you can specify the ***target timezone (in your case, its UTC)*** with the help of **`tzinfo`** parameter in the [**`TruncYear`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncYear) class.

#### Example

```
import pytz

Tracking.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('created_at', tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
```

---

To show ***year*** in the json reponse, change your serializer as,

```
class TimeseriesYearSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = VenueTSSerializer(read_only=True)
    year = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='year.year')
    count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tracking
        fields = ['venue', 'year', 'count']
```

---

### References

1. [Postgress `AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)
2. [Postgress `date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)
3. [DRF Serializer `source` argument](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: I'ved implemented this - Tracking.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('created_at', tzinfo=pytz.UTC)). I am giving it some time if its holding up, so far its been a few hours and its holding up. will update tomorrow

Comment: pardon me, what you mean by *holding up*?

Comment: meaning this solution is working as of now. I just need to observe it a bit longer as in the previous queryset, after a day, it will appear the timezone back again. So far, it looks like its ok but I need to observe.

Comment: Great...let me know the results

Comment: yup after more than a day, its still getting Z datetime. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked sources of Django Rest Framework and it looks like it uses "[current timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)" by default for `DateTimeField` but you can set it in a force manner by passing `default_timezone` equal to `"pytz.timezone('Zulu')"`. This way it will return the field value in the required timezone.

I've played with that a bit and for me it works as expected. For example for `Europe/Moscow` for my test serializer (in my project) I have output like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test 123",
    "level": 0,
    "slug": "test-123",
    "icon_code": "123",
    "image": null,
    "brand": false,
    "children": [],
    "created_at": "2019-12-09T01:55:08.438442+03:00"
  }
```

And for `Zulu` timezone I have it like

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test 123",
    "level": 0,
    "slug": "test-123",
    "icon_code": "123",
    "image": null,
    "brand": false,
    "children": [],
    "created_at": "2019-12-08T22:55:08.438442Z"
  }
```

My test field declaration is

```
created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format='iso-8601', default_timezone=pytz.timezone('Zulu'))
```

> It seems like in your source code you override "current timezone" but don't set it to a default one or etc and that's why it works right after the server restart and stops in a few hours (when a request sets the wrong timezone). So you have 2 ways to fix it - declare your fields as I did above using the `default_timezone` param or find where the current timezone value is changed). The easiest solution for the case, of course, is declaring the field timezone required but in general, of course, it should work without bugs :)

**More information:**

- https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/95d4843abeecea96754a147f4f2cca33e620ad09/rest_framework/fields.py#L1199
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield (look at `default_timezone` param)